# memoFix of Data.Function.Memoize does not free memory after itself

Tags: haskell, garbage-collection, memoization

I am wondering why the GC never frees memory for main = memo_main. If main = slow_main, the computation takes the same amount of time each time I enter 37. Due to this, the behavior I expected was to see decrease in memory allocation each time the top level memoFix returns. Yet, it is stuck at 370 MBs.

```
module Main where

import Data.Function.Memoize

memo_fib :: (Int -> Int) -> Int -> Int
memo_fib _ 0 = 1
memo_fib _ 1 = 1
memo_fib f n = f (n-1) + f (n-2)

memo_main = interact $ unlines . map (\x -> show $ memoFix memo_fib $ read x) . lines

slow_fib 0 = 1
slow_fib 1 = 1
slow_fib n = slow_fib (n-1) + slow_fib (n-2)

slow_main = interact $ unlines . map (\x -> show $ slow_fib $ read x) . lines

main :: IO ()
main = memo_main
```

UPD: Resolved. Memory was actually freed, but not returned to the OS. This is per design of GHC RTS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a couple notes:

Are you compiling with optimization? Optimization might cause `memoFix memo_fib` to be lifted out of the lambda, since it doesn't depend on `x`, thus sharing the memo table across all calls.

Another thing to keep in mind is that the GHC runtime never shrinks the heap.  As soon as it has allocated a certain amount of memory, the GC collects it but keeps it around for other parts of the program to use, rather than freeing it to the OS.  So the GC may be collecting this after all, but you won't see it with whatever tool you're using to watch it.

Comment: Thank you. GHC indeed does shrink the heap if you believe [this](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.8.2/html/users_guide/runtime-control.html) document.
However it doesn't do it as eagerly as I assumed, hence the confusion. By inputting the same fairly large number multiple times in a row, I could see the allocated memory oscillating. Thank you again for your comment.